# import turtle module - always getting an error message

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, nameerror

I'm trying to import the `turtle` module but it always give me an error if I use any of its methods, e.g.

```
turtle.forward(10).
```

I've already checked my module name which is `mydesign.py`.

***Error:***

> ***Traceback*** (most recent call last):
>
> File "<*input*>", line 1, in <*module*>
>
> **NameError**: name ***'turtle'*** is not defined

Comment: Did you make sure to actually import the `turtle` module by including the lines `import turtle` at the top of your file? If you did so, and your code still isn't working, please edit your post to contain the source code for your entire program so we can take a look at it.

Comment: It's working now !! Thanks anyways !!

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Ok. So, first, do the basic thing. Make sure you have imported `turtle`. What this does is allows you to access all of the `turtle` methods (functions that you can use).

```
import turtle
```

Next, you add the bit of code you already have.

```
turtle.forward(10)
```

Finally, add `turtle.mainloop()` if you want to keep the window open. What `turtle.mainloop()` does is run the code and then keep the window open.

#### Final Code

Here is the final code. There are comments (marked with a `#` so they are not run as commands) to explain it.

```
import turtle         # Gives you access to all the turtle functions

turtle.forward(10)    # Move the turtle 10 across. This isn't very much so you may want to try using 100

turtle.mainloop()     # Keep the window open until you press the close button at the top (so you can see your marvelous work!).
```